# How to use NIO to write InputStream to File?

Tags: java, image, file, inputstream, nio

I am using following way to write `InputStream` to `File`:

```
private void writeToFile(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "C:\\Test.jpg";
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(filePath).getChannel();       
    ReadableByteChannel inChannel = Channels.newChannel(stream);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    
    while(true) {
        if(inChannel.read(buffer) == -1) {
            break;
        }
        
        buffer.flip();
        outChannel.write(buffer);
        buffer.clear();
    }
    
    inChannel.close();
    outChannel.close();
}
```

I was wondering if this is the right way to use NIO. I have read a method [`FileChannel.transferFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29), which takes three parameter:

1. ReadableByteChannel src
2. long position
3. long count

In my case I only have `src`, I don't have the `position` and `count`, is there any way I can use this method to create the file?

Also for Image is there any better way to create image only from `InputStream` and NIO?

Any information would be very useful to me. There are similar questions here, in SO, but I cannot find any particular solution which suites my case.

Comment: Why do it in such a complicated way? You can do the same in one line: `Files.copy(stream, new File("C:\\Test.jpg").toPath());`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it's not correct. You run the risk of losing data. The canonical NIO copy loop is as follows:

```
while (in.read(buffer) >= 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
{
  buffer.flip();
  out.write(buffer);
  buffer.compact();
}
```

Note the changed loop conditions, which take care of flushing the output at EOS, and the use of `compact()` instead of `clear(),` which takes care of the possibility of short writes.

Similarly the canonical `transferTo()/transferFrom()` loop is as follows:

```
long offset = 0;
long quantum = 1024*1024; // or however much you want to transfer at a time
long count;
while ((count = out.transferFrom(in, offset, quantum)) > 0)
{
    offset += count;
}
```

It must be called in a loop, as it isn't guaranteed to transfer the entire quantum.

Comment: If transferFrom returns 0 it does not mean that all bytes are actually transferred. To be 100% correct we need to know in advance the expected count from InputStream and loop till we transfer them all. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes I do. It's a strange thing that there is no proper EOS indication from these APIs.

Answer (score 52):

I would use Files.copy

```
Files.copy(is, Paths.get(filePath));
```

as for your version

1. `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` is faster - *Java will make a best effort to perform native I/O operations directly upon it.*
2. Closing is unreliable, if first fails second will never execute. Use try-with-resources instead, Channels are `AutoCloseable` too.

Comment: `transferFrom()` and `transferTo()` must be called in a loop. There is no guarantee that they transfer the requested count. That's why they return a count.

Comment: Use Files.copy(fileInputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); if file already exists.